# how do i solve AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: nltk, attributeerror, sentiment-analysis, punctuation, vader

## this is the code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

plt.style.use('ggplot')

import nltk

df = pd.read_csv('/kaggle/input/starbucks-review-play-store/starbucksEN.csv',sep=",", encoding="utf-8")
df = df.head(70000)

ax = df\['Score'\].value_counts().sort_index() \
.plot(kind='bar',
title='Count of Reviews by Stars',
figsize=(10, 5))
ax.set_xlabel('Review Stars')
plt.show()

from nltk.sentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm

sia = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()

res = {}
for i, row in tqdm(df.iterrows(), total=len(df)):
text = row\['Text'\]
myid = row\['Id'\]
res\[myid\] = sia.polarity_scores(text)
```

## this is what show up

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_27/744249663.py in \<module\>
3     text = row\['Text'\]
4     myid = row\['Id'\]
\----\> 5     res\[myid\] = sia.polarity_scores(text)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/sentiment/vader.py in polarity_scores(self, text)
360         # text, words_and_emoticons, is_cap_diff = self.preprocess(text)
361         sentitext = SentiText(
\--\> 362             text, self.constants.PUNC_LIST, self.constants.REGEX_REMOVE_PUNCTUATION
363         )
364         sentiments = \[\]

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/sentiment/vader.py in __init__(self, text, punc_list, regex_remove_punctuation)
268     def __init__(self, text, punc_list, regex_remove_punctuation):
269         if not isinstance(text, str):
\--\> 270             text = str(text.encode("utf-8"))
271         self.text = text
272         self.PUNC_LIST = punc_list

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

i'm trying to do sentiment analysis by wathing this video on youtube. here is the link to his kaggle notebook  https://www.kaggle.com/code/robikscube/sentiment-analysis-python-youtube-tutorial/notebook
i don't know what is wrong. how do i fix this?